# What is the difference between stub() vs when()?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm a bit confused with stubbing syntax.

what is the difference between:

`stub(mock.someMethod()).toReturn(10);`

and

`when(mock.someMethod()).toReturn(10);`

Comment: That would be `when().thenReturn()`; unless you use some very old version?

Comment: from the [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stub(T)) I think that they are the same but stub() is older. (returning a `DeprecatedOngoingStubbing`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`stub` method's documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stub%28T%29):

> Some users find `stub()` confusing therefore `Mockito.when(Object)` is recommended over `stub()`.

So basically they are the *same*. But as the `stub` method returns a `DeprecatedOngoingStubbing` (note the word *deprecated*), the `when` method is obviously meant to be used.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the official Mockito's [tutorial](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when%28T%29):

> `when()` is a successor of deprecated `stub(Object)`